# $G$ a group of order 210. If $G$ is commutative show it is cyclic. If $G$ is any group show it contains a subgroup of index 2.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, solution-verification, cyclic-groups, sylow-theory

$G$ a group of order 210.

**Part 1** If $G$ is commutative show it is cyclic.

Consider the prime factorization $210=(2)(3)(5)(7)$. By Sylow's theory we know that Sylow subgroups exist of order 2, 3, 5, and 7 in $G$. Let $P_i$ be a Sylow subgroup of order $i$, for $i \in \{2,3,5,7\}$. Each one of these subgroups is a cyclic group because the order is prime.

Consider the the set $P_i P_j :=\{qh|q \in P_i, h \in P_j \}$. $P_iP_j$ is a subgroup since it is closed under products and inverses (proof omitted). $|P_iP_j|=ij$ by the simple combinatorics of the number of unique ways of choosing an element from a set $i$ elements and another from a set of $j$ elements, regardless of order (commutative property).

Finally I want to show that $P_i P_j$ is cyclic because it has an element of order $ij$, and so this element generates the whole group. For $qh \in P_iP_j$ such that $q,h \ne 1$, and assume that $(qh)^n=1$. Then $q^nh^n=1$, by the commutative property. This happens if and only if $q^n=1$ and $h^n=1$, so $n$ must be a multiple of $i$ and also a multiple of $j$. Since, $i$ and $j$ are coprime, $ij$ is the smallest number that is a multiple of both $i$ and $j$, and as such is the order of $qh$.

This shows that $P_iP_j$ is cyclic. A very similar argument can be used to show that $P_2 P_3 P_5 P_7$ defined in the same way is cyclic, because 2,3,5, and 7 are coprime.

**Part 2** If $G$ is any group show it contains a subgroup of index 2.

For this part, I use the lemma that if $A$ and $B$ are finite subgroups of a group, then 
$$|AB|=\frac{|A||B|}{|A \cap B|}$$
with emphasis that for any $P_i, P_j$, where $i,j \in \{2,3,5,7\}$, are the Sylow subgroups referenced above, then $|P_i \cap P_j| = \{1\}$. If not, then $P_j$ would contain an element of order $i$, and thats a contradiction since each $P_j$ is a cyclic group. From here, it is straight-forward.
$$|P_5 P_7|=\frac{(5)(7)}{1}=35$$
Now, I claim also that $|P_3 \cap P_5P_7|=\{1\}$. If not then $P_5P_7$ would contain an element of order 3, which it cannot, because by Lagrange, 3 does not divide 35. Et voila,
$$|P_3 P_5 P_7|=\frac{|P_3||P_5 P_7|}{|P_3 \cap P_5 P_7|}=\frac{(3)(35)}{1}=105$$
The index of a subgroup of order 105 is 2.

Comment: Part 1 also follows directly form the classification of finite abelian groups, ie.., $\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z/3\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z/5\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z/7\Bbb Z\cong \Bbb Z/210\Bbb Z$. -- But how do you know that $P_3P_5P_7$ (or even $P_5P_7$) is a group?

Comment: The number $210$ is squarefree, and any abelian group of squarefree order is cyclic.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen $P_3 P_5 P_7 := \{abc|a\in P_3,b\in P_5,c\in P7\}$ is group because it is closed under the group operation and inverses. This is pretty easy to show with the commutative property. But I guess here you are referring to part B?

Comment: For part 2, you no longer assume commutative. So you don't know that $P_3P_5P_7$ is a subgroup. Correct? Of course, if 2 of $n_3, n_5, n_7$ are 1, then you're done.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simpler proof of part 1: By Cauchy's theorem, there are elements of order $2,3,5,7$. Then the product of these elements has order $210$.